# Frequency of vector combinations from a data frame

Tags: r

I have a data frame and I have all possible combinations between columns. I would like to get the frequency of every combination vector from my data frame.
For instance:

```
> DF
   A  B   C
1 11  2 432
2 11  3 432
3 13  1 241
4 13  4 241
5 13  5 241
6 28 42  35
7 28 61  35
> f
[[1]]
[1] "A" "B"

[[2]]
[1] "A" "C"

[[3]]
[1] "B" "C"

[[4]]
[1] "A" "B" "C"
```

Here's my code, with generous contributions from members of this community:

```
> library(plyr)
> res=list()
> for (j in 1:length(f)){
+       res[[j]]=count(DF,f[[j]]) 
+ }
> res
[[1]]
   A  B freq
1 11  2    1
2 11  3    1
3 13  1    1
4 13  4    1
5 13  5    1
6 28 42    1
7 28 61    1

[[2]]
   A   C freq
1 11 432    2
2 13 241    3
3 28  35    2

[[3]]
   B   C freq
1  1 241    1
2  2 432    1
3  3 432    1
4  4 241    1
5  5 241    1
6 42  35    1
7 61  35    1

[[4]]
   A  B   C freq
1 11  2 432    1
2 11  3 432    1
3 13  1 241    1
4 13  4 241    1
5 13  5 241    1
6 28 42  35    1
7 28 61  35    1
```

It works well, even with 10000x8 data frames. And now I am going to get the combinations with freq>1. Two ways with the same output.

```
> lapply(res, subset, freq > 1)
```

or

```
> threshold <- 1
> purrr::map(res, function(x) {
+   x[x[["freq"]] > threshold, ]
+ })

[[1]]
[1] A    B    freq
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)

[[2]]
   A   C freq
1 11 432    2
2 13 241    3
3 28  35    2

[[3]]
[1] B    C    freq
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)

[[4]]
[1] A    B    C    freq
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

Issues:

- I have run the code with "table" instead of "count", but it does not work. I would like to compare the time of execution between those functions with big data frames.
- I would like to divide and sort by freq the final output, in order to get something like this:

  ```
  [[1]]
     A   C freq
  1 13 241    3

  [[2]]
     A   C freq
  1 11 432    2

  [[3]]
     A   C freq
  1 28  35    2
  ```

Thank you for any help you can provide.

Comment: Try `library(tidyverse); f %>% map(~ DF %>% select(.x) %>% count(!!! rlang::syms(names(.))) %>% filter(n > threshold)) %>% Filter(nrow, .) %>% map(~ .x %>% arrange(desc(n)) %>% split(., 1:nrow(.)))`

Comment: Thank you, akrun. Is there a way to convert a tibble list to a standard list?

Comment: Use the `as.data.frame` before the `split`.  Posted in the solution